# Self-daemonizing bash script

Tags: bash, daemon

I want to make a script to be ***self-daemonizing***, i.e., no need to invoke `nohup $SCRIPT &>/dev/null &` manually on the shell prompt.

My plan is to create a section of code like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTNAME="$0"

...

# Preps are done above
if [[ "$1" != "--daemonize" ]]; then
    nohup "$SCRIPTNAME" --daemonize "${PARAMS[@]}" &>/dev/null &
    exit $?
fi

# Rest of the code are the actual procedures of the daemon
```

Is this wise? Do you have better alternatives?

Comment: You should use double quotes around `$SCRIPTNAME` and `$1` at least; otherwise you run into trouble if there are spaces in these values.

Comment: @Alfe you're right. I forgot the double quotes. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are things I see.

```
if [[ $1 != "--daemonize" ]]; then
```

Shouln't that be `== --daemonize?`

```
nohup $SCRIPTNAME --daemonize "${PARAMS[@]}" &>/dev/null &
```

Instead of calling your script again, you could just summon a subshell that's placed in a background:

```
(
    Codes that run in daemon mode.
) </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

Or

```
function daemon_mode {
    Codes that run in daemon mode.
}

daemon_mode </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

Comment: There's no need for parentheses in the last version. Function will be run in the new subshell anyway because of &.

Comment: Oh yes. I just added the `function` feature so I didn't notice it much thanks.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Yes that looks much more elegant. The `[[ "$1" != --daemonize ]]` is correct. Basically, if the script is not invoked using the `--daemonize` parameter, it will relaunch itself passing the `--daemonize` parameter. However, I can see that your solution is much more elegant, so the test is moot. Thank you!