# Is it possible to call a bash shell script using supervisord?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, supervisord

I'm trying to call [this shell script](https://github.com/apache/directory-kerby/blob/trunk/kerby-dist/kdc-dist/bin/start-kdc.sh) using supervisord. supervisorctl reports the following error when trying to start the process:

> kerby-kdc                           FATAL     Exited too quickly
> (process log may have details)

I checked the kerby logs but no errors were reported.

I configured the process in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` as follows:

```
[program:kerby-kdc]
command=bash -c "/home/test/kerberos/server/kdc-dist/bin/start-kdc.sh" /home/test/kerberos/server/kdc-dist/conf /home/test/kerberos/server/kdc-dist/runtime
user=test
environment=JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
```

Is there something wrong with this configuration?

Comment: What is start-kdc.sh? You can't use supervisord with something that self daemonizes

Comment: start-kdc.sh is [this shell script](https://github.com/apache/directory-kerby/blob/trunk/kerby-dist/kdc-dist/bin/start-kdc.sh). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954527/self-daemonizing-bash-script) about self-daemonizing but I don't see nohup in the script. Am I missing something? If I run the shell script on the command line via `sh start-kdc.sh`, it gains control of the command line (i.e. it doesn't run in the background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell script referenced in the OP contains the following:

```
java $DEBUG \
-classpath target/lib/*:. \
-DKERBY_LOGFILE=kdc \
org.apache.kerby.kerberos.kdc.KerbyKdcServer -start $args
```

Note that the classpath is relative. When supervisord tries to execute the java command, the JVM will be unable to find the class `org.apache.kerby.kerberos.kdc.KerbyKdcServer`. That's because `target/lib` doesn't exist relative to the supervisord execution path.

The classpath needs to be absolute or a CLASSPATH environment variable needs to be added to the supervisord.conf file.